# Laravel And AJAX getting Intenal Server Error on model save method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Basically, I'm trying to send data that was sent from Ajax to Laravel controller. Problem is that I'm always getting ***AJAX error: error: Internal Server Error***. I have googled a lot about this problem and found that I need to also send **csrf token**. So here's my ajax

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/customer/getAjax', // This is the url we gave in the route
                method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

                    if (token) {
                        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                    }
                },
                data: obj, // a JSON object to send back
                success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                    console.log("asds " + response);
                    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

And here's my controller

```
class MainPage extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all(); // This will get all the request data.


       // $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required|max:100', 'body' => 'required|min:10']);

        $post = new Post;
        $post->user_id = $data['user_id'];
        $post->title = $data['title'];
        $post->body = $data['body'];
        $post->post_type = $data['post_type'];
        //$post->created_at = $data['created_at'];
        $post->user_name = $data['user_name'];
        $post->save(); // Here's where I get Error!!!

        return "Ok"
    }
```

And also here's my route

```
Route::post('/customer/getAjax', 'MainPage@store');
```

If I delete `$post->save();` Everything is working and I even get response Ok, however data is not saved I also tried to include  `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in `html head`. However I get same issue.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your *$post-save* in a try.. catch.. and see what the error is?

Comment: you have to send `CSRF-TOKEN` in data. like `data: { column1: column1,
_token: CSRF_TOKEN }`. Or you can set it in header.

Comment: First try this, in your `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` Add your route in `protected $except = [
        //
    ];` If that works, then your ajax request is not sending the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add token to meta like here:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

You should add in your ajax constructor next option

```
     method: 'POST',
     ....
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')},
     ....
```

Comment: Thank You very much! You save me a lot of time. I will accept your answer as soon as  I can! :)